# How to Change Page's Background Color, Windows Phone 8.1 C# XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, visual-studio-2015

I want to change Page's Background Color from Code Behind.
But I don't know how to do this.

Please tell me how to write Code about changing Background Color.

I use Visual Studio 2015 C# XAML enviroment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set the page's background color in code behind, we should get the page object from xaml. So add x:Name property for the page and set the background color from code behind.

**XAML Code**

```
    <Page   ...  x:Name="thispage">
```

**Code Behind**

```
    SolidColorBrush redbrush=new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);//your color        
    thispage.Background = redbrush;
```

Comment: Thank you Sunteen. it is easy to understand. And It worked!